# How can I get my candidate score, as in Mod elections

Tags: discussion, election

See any [election page](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/6).

Out of curiosity, is this an HTML thing?

[image: box shown below nomination showing 4 categories of the candidate score and the total]

...or is this a function of Flair?

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate your own (hypothetical) score?

Comment: @Laurel Well I can find the info (such as I got 36 outa 40) on mod stuff...but is there an easier way to collate this data and post it in a boxie  thingie? I just wanna compare myself to the other candidates...mostly an ego thing, I guess

Comment: Nothing built in but it wouldn't be too hard to create manually, adding your numbers from SEDE.

Comment: @Laurel Is that what you did?

Comment: Well, I guess it's true that you can run for moderator to get a flair like this, but you should only do that if you're willing to moderate :p

Comment: @Laurel I have been an active participant on the review queues since like 5 years ago, but I am not interested in performing official duties. It's just more headache. I just wanted to know if this is a flair only for mod elections, and was mildly interested in doing a pissing contest...

Comment: You can easily calculate your scores with this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/1449330/moderator-election-score) by inputting your user id (that's the number in your profile's URL). Note that the data only updates every Sunday so it might be slightly stale. Is that what you're looking for or do you want something that also looks like that flair?

Comment: What you show is built into the Election pages. In fact, prior years' pages show *current* data. It's not "flair", at least, not flair as on other pages; it's data extracted from live SEDE presented using HTML. But then that describes flair as well. What is it that you're asking for?

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine If it helps with your pissing contest, given the SEDE query Laurel provided, I’d have a score of 39/40, missing only the silver “Refiner” badge (edit and answer 50 questions, both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0). I really only edit Qs to make them legible if they’re big walls of text, to see if there’s something *worth answering* in there. If a question doesn’t need any edits to answer, I don’t bother — minor things like typos don’t faze me. If the question is so obviously off-topic or misguided no editing can rescue it, then I neither edit nor answer.

Comment: @DanBron We could have had a Moderator named Dan Bron with that score, but you, oh no no no, you wouldn't let ELU have nice things. ;) Dan Bron's one of the best all round user I've ever met on the SE. And many would agree.

Comment: @NVZ We don’t need a mod named Dan Bron with that pathetic score, because we can have one named NVZ with a perfect 40/40 ;) I’ve enjoyed my interactions with you since the day you joined, and I am very pleased you are running indeed.

Comment: In the ELU election chat room there's a bot you can speak to. Just type in "@electionbot what's my candidate score?" Give it a try.

Comment: "If nominated, I will not run..." @DanBron...? Your comment sounds like the type of attitude we need more of...

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine As the immortal Groucho Marx once said, I would not deign to join any club which would accept me as a member. The issue with positions of power is only those who seek power will run for them…

Answer (score 8):

Here is a SEDE query that accepts a list of user IDs and outputs your scores: [Candidate Score](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/298418/candidate-score). Your ID is the number in the URL for [your profile](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/current): `https://english.stackexchange.com/users/####/name`. The data in SEDE is updated only every Sunday. You can use this query for any site if you switch sites (using the "search by name or url box"); you will have to get your ID for that site's profile to use because it'll be different.

If you just want the total, try election chat with "[What is my candidate score](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/134773?m=60727042#60727042)". If ElectionBot is there, it will answer.

If you wanted to go further, you could use [Dev Tools](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2018/05/01/live-editing-html-css-chrome-devtools/) to edit the source of the election page in your browser to make it look like your "candidate flair", then take a screenshot.

It would be handy to have this information more readily available. For that, see Meta SE: [I would like to see my mod candidate score, preferrably on my user page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273494/323179)

Comment: TXS Laurel...this was a fascinating description of a process that is mostly opaque for most users. I voted  you as this appears to be the type of help I would expect from a mod

Answer (score 2):

Now that @OlegValteriswithUkraine has installed ElectionBot (which seems to be hosted courtesy of @SamuelLiew), you can go to the [2022 English Language & Usage Stack Exchange Moderator Election Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134773/2022-english-language-usage-stack-exchange-moderator-election-chat) and type the following to get your candidate score:

- @ElectionBot What is my candidate score

NB: ElectionBot is room-specific. I tried it out in the main EL&U chat room (during an election), and it didn't work.

Comment: The calculation works for any user on any site where an election is being held.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Nice! Thanks for checking. Unfortunately, having it active only during elections puts a time limit of a couple of days on the effectiveness of this answer (until the next election).

Comment: I don't think ElectionBot retires, you might have to hunt it down. Or maybe it magically appears whenever it is pinged. I don't know, I could try on a site where there's no election.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It needs to be specially installed. But since the calculation isn't intrinsically linked to the election process, perhaps it would persist. Give it a try in 3 days.